# Deciding how many ports to use for link aggregation between switches

Tags: networking

I have 2 48 port gigabit switched for workstations and devices.  Right now they are each connected to our Meraki router via 1 single GigE.  I am going to connect the two switches together with LACP instead.  How many ports should I use to connect the switches, is there a max before I have diminishing returns?

Answer (score 2):

Well generally you can only do 2, 4 and sometimes 8-way Etherchannel/LACP port groups - so simply look at your traffic, if it's enough to saturate 1Gb then go with 2 links, if that's saturated then go for 4 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are diminishing returns. Do you have any idea how much traffic is passing through the switches? Is there any storage traffic or high bandwidth activity (NAS, video, etc?). My default for a small setup like that is *two ports*.

Also, can you please provide the make/model of the switch?